# Shift key does not fully work in Juypter Notebook's terminal

Tags: keystrokes, jupyter

The <kbd>Shift</kbd> key sometimes does not seem to work in emacs, when emacs is launched in Jupyter Notebook's terminal (in non-window mode). Other meta keys such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> on a PC keyboard work as usual.

When trying to move to the end of the buffer with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>, nothing happens. This is tested with Jupyter Hub on Ubuntu 18.04, and the clients are Firefox and Chrome.

However, the Shift key seems to work for selecting multiple lines.

I am not sure whether this relates to how browsers handle the Shift key, or where it went wrong.

Does any one have experience using emacs in Jupyter's terminal and know of a fix?